# Javascript: How to use on() method with each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've learnt that `on()` ables to bind new injected elements:

```
$(document).on( eventName, selector, function(){} );
```

I want my customized timecountdown function applies to all $('.timecountdown') when page is loaded, which also applies to newly retrieved account. My code is shown below:

```
<html>
<div class="timecountdown">50seconds</div>
<div class="timecountdown">20seconds</div>
<div class="timecountdown">60seconds</div>
...
...
...
</html>
<script>
$(function(){
$('.timecountdown').each(function(){
   //code to counting down time on each elements using by javascript setInterval() 
     function, which minus one to the residual integer for every seconds.
   //code to delete old account when time hits zero, then retrieve new accounts 
     via ajax post method     
     $.post("accountupdate.php", {id:id}, function(result){
       code to display new <div class="timecountdown">Xseconds</div> account
     })

})
</scirpt>
```

I tried:

```
 $(document).on(each, $('.timecountdown'), function(){
 code to countdown time, delete and retrieve
 } );
```

Comment: `.on()`  binds an event handler. Which event are you trying to handle? What is the desired behaviour? The second line of your question shows the correct format for binding delegated event handlers with `.on()`, but then your example code completely ignores that because `each` is not an event name and `$('timecountdown')` is not a selector. Did you mean `$(document).on('click', '.timecountdown', function() { /* something */ });`? (Where `'click'` is an example event.)

Comment: @nnnnnn I want my customized timecountdown function applies to all $('.timecountdown') when page is loaded, which also applies to newly retrieved account

Comment: `.on()` doesn't make sense for that. Just apply your countdown function directly to the newly added element within the `$.post()` success handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn That's what I did originally, but the newly retrieved each() in the retrieved file applies to old elements as well, damaged my page.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said to apply it *directly to the newly added element*. The code that adds the new element should have a reference to that element (if not it should be easy enough to modify it so it has a reference).

Comment: @nnnnnn Would you mind wrote a bit of code or pseudocode to illustrate?  I have problem understanding what u mean by directly. What I did was including the same javascript in the posted file. And I also tried to reference the new accounts by given them a new class to reference them in the retrieved selector, however, since the new retrieved elements will count down to zero and retrieve another new account, it goes back to my problem again.

Answer (score 0):

`each` is not an event method but it is for iterating over DOM elements. [on](http://api.jquery.com/on) method is used only for event handling so you don't need to worry about event delegation method while using [each](http://api.jquery.com/each) method.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery each() method is a generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays whereas on() method attaches an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

May be you can try like this

```
$("body").on({
    mouseover: function() {
            $('.timecountdown').each(function(){
               $.post("accountupdate.php", {id:id}, function(result){
                   code to display new <div class="timecountdown">Xseconds</div> account
                });
            });
    }
});
```